# Trying to bind pop-up in leaflet via GeoServer GetFeatureInfo. Is there anything wrong in my code?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, leaflet

Simple Leaflet Map

```
<script
    src="js/leaflet.js"> </script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>



     var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: "Data by OpenStreetMap"
    });

var dep = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/TestpostGIS/wms", {
    layers: 'TestpostGIS:departments',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
isBaselayer:false,

});



var ground = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ucity/wms", {
    layers: ' ucity:ground',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,

});
var map = new L.Map('map', {
    center: new L.LatLng(15, 0),
    zoom: 2,
    layers: [osm, dep,ground],
    zoomControl: true
    });

var departments={
    "Departments":dep
}

var grounds={
    "Grounds":ground
}

var layerControl = L.control.layers(departments, grounds);
    map.addControl(layerControl);

ms_url="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/TestpostGIS/wms";
map.addEventListener('click', Identify);
function Identify(e) 
{
    // set parameters needed for GetFeatureInfo WMS request
    var BBOX = map.getBounds().toBBoxString();
    var WIDTH = map.getSize().x;
    var HEIGHT = map.getSize().y;
    var X = map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).x;
     var Y = map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).y;
     // compose the URL for the request
    var URL = ms_url + 'SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&LAYERS=TestpostGIS:departments&QUERY_LAYERS=TestpostGIS:departments&BBOX='+BBOX+'&FEATURE_COUNT=1&HEIGHT='+HEIGHT+'&WIDTH='+WIDTH+'&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&X='+X+'&Y='+Y;


    //send the asynchronous HTTP request using jQuery $.ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        dataType: "html",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) 
        {
            var popup = new L.Popup
            ({
                maxWidth: 300
            });

            popup.setContent(data);
            popup.setLatLng(e.latlng);
            map.openPopup(popup);
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The construction of your WMS request appears to be missing a ? after the initial url.

```
ms_url="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/TestpostGIS/wms";
....
var URL = ms_url + '?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&LAYERS=TestpostGIS:departments&QUERY_LAYERS=TestpostGIS:departments&BBOX='+BBOX+'&FEATURE_COUNT=1&HEIGHT='+HEIGHT+'&WIDTH='+WIDTH+'&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&X='+X+'&Y='+Y;
```